# Correlation maximization (Canonical correlation analysis)

Tags: probability, optimization, linear-transformations, correlation

A question concerning part b):

[image]

I replaced $X$ with $X=Xw_x$ and $Y$ with $Y=Yw_y$ and took the derivative wrt $w_x$ and $w_y$. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get to the end as my dimensions do not match after applying the derivative quotient rule. Then, I looked at the solution and realized that the solution was completely different from mine.

[image]

My questions are:

1) Why doesn't the denominator matter? It contains the variables we're optimizing...

2) Why are we setting values for variances (with value 1 in this example)? If they don't matter shouldn't we just maximize the nominator?

3) Why can't I just normally optimize by taking the derivative of the **whole** Corr expression without any comments about the denominator and nominator and optimize all together?

NB: I know how Lagrange multipliers work, I just don't understand how/why we get the constraints in this example.

Comment: A well written-formatted question will likely to draw more attention which increases the likelihood of getting (better) answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem corresponds to the well-known **Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA)**.

Assuming two zero-mean random vectors ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$, we define $x$ and $y$ as linear combinations of the elements of ${\bf x}$ and ${\bf y}$ (i.e. $x = {\bf x}^T{\bf w}_x$ and $y = {\bf y}^T{\bf w}_y$). 
What we want in CCA is to find ${\bf w}_x$ and ${\bf w}_y$ that maximize the correlation between $x$ and $y$.

We define the correlation coefficient as:
$$
\rho = \frac{E[xy]}{\sqrt{E[x^2]E[y^2]}}
=\frac{E[{\bf w}_x^T {\bf x} {\bf y}^T {\bf w}_y]}
{\sqrt{E[{\bf w}_x^T {\bf x} {\bf x}^T {\bf w}_x]E[{\bf w}_y^T {\bf y} {\bf y}^T {\bf w}_y]}}
=\frac{{\bf w}_x^T E[{\bf x} {\bf y}^T] {\bf w}_y}
{\sqrt{{\bf w}_x^T E[{\bf x} {\bf x}^T] {\bf w}_x {\bf w}_y^T E[{\bf y} {\bf y}^T] {\bf w}_y}}
=\frac{{\bf w}_x^T {\bf C}_{xy} {\bf w}_y}
{\sqrt{{\bf w}_x^T {\bf C}_{xx} {\bf w}_x {\bf w}_y^T {\bf C}_{yy} {\bf w}_y}}
$$

Note that $\rho$ is the same regardless of the *scaling* of ${\bf w}_x$ and ${\bf w}_y$. If, for e.g. we multiply ${\bf w}_x$ by $\alpha$ and ${\bf w}_y$ by $\beta$ we get the original $\rho$:

$$
\rho=\frac{\alpha{\bf w}_x^T {\bf C}_{xy} \beta{\bf w}_y}
{\sqrt{\alpha{\bf w}_x^T {\bf C}_{xx} \alpha{\bf w}_x \beta{\bf w}_y^T {\bf C}_{yy} \beta{\bf w}_y}}
=\frac{\alpha \beta {\bf w}_x^T {\bf C}_{xy} {\bf w}_y}
{\sqrt{\alpha^2\beta^2}\sqrt{{\bf w}_x^T {\bf C}_{xx} {\bf w}_x {\bf w}_y^T {\bf C}_{yy} {\bf w}_y}}
$$

This means that we can always play (re-scale) ${\bf w}_x$ and ${\bf w}_y$ to modify the denominator without affecting $\rho$. Particularly, we use this fact to simplify the problem by setting to get solutions that satisfy:
$$
{\bf w}_x^T {\bf C}_{xx} {\bf w}_x = 1\\
{\bf w}_y^T {\bf C}_{yy} {\bf w}_y = 1
$$

Hence, the problem becomes optimizing the numerator of $\rho$ subject to the previous constraints.

Comment: thank you for answering questions 1) and 2). Could you please elaborate on 3) as well?

Comment: @Lola, optimizing rational functions (especially multi-variable functions) is not always easy. So, we take advantage of the fact that our problem is equivalent to setting a fixed value for the denominator (here 1) and only optimize the numerator.